# makeMove function is not working as i wish

Tags: c, function, dev-c++

void makeMove(int player, int move) {
int i, stones, nextPit;

```
// Get the number of stones in the selected pit
stones = board[player * 6 + move];
board[player * 6 + move] = 0;  // Clear the pit

// Distribute the stones
nextPit = player * 6 + move + 1;  // Start at the next pit
for (i = 0; i < stones; i++) {
    // Skip the opponent's mancala
    if (nextPit == (player ^ 1) * 6 + 6) {
        nextPit++;  
    }

    // Place a stone in the pit
    board[nextPit]++;
    nextPit++;  // Move to the next pit

    // Wrap around to to the beginning of the board
    if (nextPit == BOARD_SIZE) {
        nextPit = 0;
    }
}
```

so this function takes all the stones from the chosen pit and puts the stones one by one on to the next pits
example : 4 4 4 4 4 if you choose the first pit it goes like 0 5 5 5 5 but i want it to be 1 5 5 5 4
i want this function to take all the stones from the chosen pit and put one back to the chosen pit and then start to put next pits

i am a 2 month computer engineering student im new to this i didnt try much if you can explain this code to me it would mean the world

Comment: In your description you say you want to put one back in the pit you took from. In your code, you say you want to start putting back at the next pit, instead. Those are different. Change your code to start where you want it to.

Comment: Take "all stones _less one_" from the source pit... Don't complicate code trying to "put one stone back"...

Comment: @Fe2O3 good idea, but if you do that, you need to change where or how the modular arithmetic is handled also